# Grid align horizontal center is not works

Tags: html, css, css-grid

```css
.parent{
  border:1px solid red;
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
}

.child{
  background:green;
  align-self:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child" style="justify-self: center;">
    I am child
  </div>
</div>
```

I am looking a solution to let child should align itself to center. so i can create a class name for `left, right, and center` will use across.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's happening here for you is automatic grid placement. Technically speaking the item is aligned to the center inside the first column you created. The problem is that it ends up all the way on the left because that's where your first column actually is.

There's a few ways you can approach this if you want to continue using CSS Grid for this layout concept. But the problem with a 12 col grid is that there won't be a "center" without some offsetting or transforms.

I recommend you use the following if you really only need one row with 3 possible placements. It's a 13 col grid with a defined height of a single row, this ensures if the items are being shuffled out of order (if left is second like my example) that they won't jump to a second implied row.

```css
.parent{
  border:1px solid red;
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(13, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: 60px;
}

.center{
  background:green;
  grid-column: 7/8;
  grid-row: 1/2;
}
.left {
  background: red;
  grid-column: 1/2;
  grid-row: 1/2;
}
.right {
  background: blue;
  grid-column: 13/14;
  grid-row: 1/2;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="center">
    I am child
  </div>
  <div class="left">
    Me too
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    Also me
  </div>
</div>
```

Edit: You can also use flexbox and drop some of the complexity and get better responsiveness by using the order property and justifying the content as space-between.

```css
.parent {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.center {
  background: green;
  order: 2
}

.left {
  background: red;
  order: 1
}

.right {
  background: blue;
  order: 3
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="center">
    I am child
  </div>
  <div class="left">
    Me too
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    Also me
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I completely agree. the issue is, when the grid being as 13 column in desktop will converted to 8 column in tablet. so I do not have a dynamic calculation to find my center column. is there a way to do it? like : `  grid-column: 2/total-columns;` ?

Comment: I don't understand how 13 will become 8 in tablet unless you're explicitly telling it to with a media query. However, you can just make the media query for 7 col's instead of 8 and have a media query for each element that places it into the correct grid-column based on each media query. Even numbers have no center column, odd numbers always do.

If what you're looking for is a solution to automate the placement into the grid based on the number of columns I don't know the compatibility of grid-column and calc but you can use vars like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/JHeth/Lafxy7tu/9/)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an optimized version with flexible values that can work with any number of columns.

I will consider CSS variables to easily adjust the template and the center element. For the left and right we only need `1` and `-1`

```css
.parent{
  --n:6;
  
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(calc(2*var(--n)), 1fr);
  grid-auto-flow:dense;
  margin:5px;
 outline:1px solid;
}

.left{
  grid-column-start:1;
}
.right{
  grid-column-end:-1;
  text-align:right;
}
.center {
  grid-column:calc(var(--n))/span 2;
  text-align:center;
}


.parent > * {
 border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="left">
    left
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    right
  </div>
  <div class="center">
    center
  </div>
</div>

<div class="parent" style="--n:3">
  <div class="left">
    left
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    right
  </div>
  <div class="center">
    center
  </div>
</div>

<div class="parent" style="--n:10">
  <div class="left">
    left
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    right
  </div>
  <div class="center">
    center
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.parent {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(1, 1fr);
}
```

Comment: yes, I know about it. but i am looking a solution to keep the template-columns with '12 or x number.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.